# Manipulating differentials for integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

Integration by parts tells us that

$$ \int_a^b u(x) \frac{d v(x)}{dx} dx = u(x)v(x)\bigg|_a^b - \int_a ^b v(x) \frac{d u(x)}{dx} dx. $$

I have also seen the equivalent formula

$$ \int_a^b u(x) d v(x) = u(x)v(x)\bigg|_a^b - \int_a ^b v(x) d u(x). $$

Now the proof I have seen of this is by noting $ \frac{d v(x)}{dx}dx = dv(x) $ and similarly $ \frac{d u(x)}{dx} dx = du(x)$. This does not seem very rigorous to me. How can I just manipulate differentials like that? Is there a more rigorous proof of the second formula?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first formula deals with Riemann integrals and works under certain assumptions. The second formula is for Riemann-Stieltjes integral and it works under a different and more general set of assumptions. Also it is possible to show that with some assumptions on $u, v $ we can convert a Riemann-Stieltjes integral into a Riemann integral via the equation $$\int_{a}^{b} u(x)\, dv(x) =\int_{a} ^{b} u(x) v'(x) \, dx$$ so that both the formulas of your question are equivalent. One of the conditions under which the second formula holds is that one of the functions $u, v$ is continuous and the other function is of bounded variation in $[a, b] $. You can perhaps study the theory of Riemann-Stieltjes integral from Tom M. Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis* to get more details and proofs of these very standard results.

Comment: I think he wasn't talking about Riemann-Stieltjes integral!